# Improving the results of CNN

Tags: keras, cnn, image-classification, confusion-matrix

**Edit 2** I solved my problem. The issue was caused by the validation_generator. I used the method flow_from_directory with shuffle = true. By changing the value to false and calling the method validation_generator.reset() before model.predict_generator() for computing the confusion matrix solved my problem. The reset()-method seems to be very important.

**Edit:** I was able to isolate the problem a little. I noticed that evaluate_generator method returns the correct values from the training, e.g. [0.068286080902908, 0.9853515625]. However, the predict_generator() method behaves strangely. The results look like this:

[[8.8930092e-06 5.8127771e-04 3.8436747e-06 7.7528159e-07 9.9940526e-01]
 [1.4138629e-03 9.9854565e-01 5.4473304e-07 3.9719587e-05 1.8904993e-07]
 [9.0803866e-07 2.7020766e-05 7.9189061e-07 4.9350000e-09 9.9997127e-01]
 ...
 [5.0964586e-06 4.5610027e-04 2.6184430e-06 1.6962146e-07 9.9953604e-01]
 [2.9692460e-08 3.1284328e-10 4.7919415e-09 1.0000000e+00 1.4161311e-12]
 [2.1354626e-06 9.6519925e-06 1.9460406e-07 4.6475903e-09 9.9998796e-01]]

**####**

I did some image classification with a CNN. The Accuracy of the training and validation set are high and the losses for both of them are low. However, my confusion matrix does not have the typical diagonal from the upper left to lower right. If I understand the confusion matrix correctly, I have a lot of misclassifications. So, how can I improve my model to get better results?

The distribution of samples each class is:

early: 800
healthy: 749
late: 764
leaf mold: 761
yellow: 708

The Structure of the model:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',input_shape=(150, 150, 
3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Dropout(0.15))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.6))
model.add(layers.Dense(150, activation='relu', 
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.002)))
model.add(layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3),
metrics=['acc'])
```

These are the accuracy and losses of the training:

```
Epoch 00067: val_loss did not improve from 0.08283
Epoch 68/200
230/230 [==============================] - 56s 243ms/step - loss: 0.0893 - 
acc: 0.9793 - val_loss: 0.0876 - val_acc: 0.9784

Epoch 00068: val_loss did not improve from 0.08283
Epoch 69/200
230/230 [==============================] - 58s 250ms/step - loss: 0.0874 - 
acc: 0.9774 - val_loss: 0.1209 - val_acc: 0.9684

Epoch 00069: val_loss did not improve from 0.08283
Epoch 70/200
230/230 [==============================] - 57s 246ms/step - loss: 0.0879 - 
acc: 0.9803 - val_loss: 0.1384 - val_acc: 0.9706

Epoch 00070: val_loss did not improve from 0.08283
Epoch 71/200
230/230 [==============================] - 59s 257ms/step - loss: 0.0903 - 
acc: 0.9783 - val_loss: 0.1352 - val_acc: 0.9728

Epoch 00071: val_loss did not improve from 0.08283
Epoch 72/200
230/230 [==============================] - 58s 250ms/step - loss: 0.0852 - 
acc: 0.9798 - val_loss: 0.1324 - val_acc: 0.9621

Epoch 00072: val_loss did not improve from 0.08283
Epoch 73/200
230/230 [==============================] - 58s 250ms/step - loss: 0.0831 - 
acc: 0.9815 - val_loss: 0.1634 - val_acc: 0.9574

Epoch 00073: val_loss did not improve from 0.08283
Epoch 74/200
230/230 [==============================] - 57s 246ms/step - loss: 0.0824 - 
acc: 0.9816 - val_loss: 0.1280 - val_acc: 0.9640

Epoch 00074: val_loss did not improve from 0.08283
Epoch 75/200
230/230 [==============================] - 57s 247ms/step - loss: 0.0869 - 
acc: 0.9774 - val_loss: 0.0777 - val_acc: 0.9882

Epoch 00075: val_loss improved from 0.08283 to 0.07765, saving model to 
C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/best_model_7.h5
Epoch 76/200
230/230 [==============================] - 56s 243ms/step - loss: 0.0739 - 
acc: 0.9851 - val_loss: 0.0683 - val_acc: 0.9851

Epoch 00076: val_loss improved from 0.07765 to 0.06826, saving model to 
C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/best_model_7.h5
```

[image: Accuracy and losses]
[image: confusion matrix]

Comment: I had a similar problem: I posted my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55991598/9524424

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit strange... one problem may be that you do not have too many training samples. Do you use a pretrained model? If not, using a pretrained model can potentially improve classification accuracy (especially with limited training samples). 
https://keras.io/applications/

**-Edit-** This is a good sample code: https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.3-using-a-pretrained-convnet.ipynb

Adjusted for multilass:

```
import keras

from keras.applications import VGG16

conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                  include_top=False,
                  input_shape=(150, 150, 3))

import os
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

base_dir = 'C:/kerasimages'

train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'val')
test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'test')

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
batch_size = 20

def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 4, 4, 512))
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count))
    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')
    i = 0
    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch
        labels[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        if i * batch_size >= sample_count:
            # Note that since generators yield data indefinitely in a loop,
            # we must `break` after every image has been seen once.
            break
    return features, labels

train_features, train_labels = extract_features(train_dir, 2000)
validation_features, validation_labels = extract_features(validation_dir, 1000)
test_features, test_labels = extract_features(test_dir, 1000)

from keras.utils import to_categorical
print(train_labels)
print(train_labels.shape)
train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
print(train_labels)
print(train_labels.shape)
validation_labels = to_categorical(validation_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

train_features = np.reshape(train_features, (2000, 4 * 4 * 512))
validation_features = np.reshape(validation_features, (1000, 4 * 4 * 512))
test_features = np.reshape(test_features, (1000, 4 * 4 * 512))

from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras import optimizers

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
# NUMBER OF CLASSES
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

conv_base.trainable = False

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      rotation_range=40,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest')

# Note that the validation data should not be augmented!
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        # This is the target directory
        train_dir,
        # All images will be resized to 150x150
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=20,
        # Since we use categorical_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels
        class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dir,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='categorical')

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),
              metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=100,
      epochs=30,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      validation_steps=50,
      verbose=2)


#######################################
# Fine tuning

#conv_base.summary()
conv_base.trainable = True

set_trainable = False
for layer in conv_base.layers:
    if layer.name == 'block5_conv1':
        set_trainable = True
    if set_trainable:
        layer.trainable = True
    else:
        layer.trainable = False

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-5),
              metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=100,
      epochs=100,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      validation_steps=50)

model.save('my_model_multiclass.hdf5')
```